# transfer dataRow to new dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset that I read in from a complex xml structure....

here is a basic version of it, for the sake of the question

```
<cars>
    <car>
       <carName>Golf</carName>
       <engine>
          <model></model>
       </engine>
    <//car>
    <car>
       <carName>Dodge</carName>
       <engine>
          <model></model>
       </engine>
    <//car>
 </cars>
```

Firstly I create the dataset to get the whole document.... (and I read this from file)

```
 DataSet dsCars = new DataSet();
 dsConfiguration.ReadXml("allcars.xml"));
```

Next I want to loop through all car rows.. to do this I use the following code:

```
 foreach(DataRow carDataRow in dsCars.Tables["Car"].Rows)
```

Now in this loop, I want to inject the car row (AND all its sub content) into a new dataset

So in the foreach loop I have code to

1. Create the new dataset
2. Create a new datatable =  CarList2
3. Import the row using : tempTaskTable2.ImportRow(carDataRow);

But when I serialize to file using: tempTaskDS.WriteXml(@"c:\test.xml");

The newly created datatable = Carlist2 is blank and contains no data at all...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are adding references. Did you use the clone() method?

Comment: No I used the import row function of the dataTable.

Comment: One new dataset for each car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you could try this in the loop:

```
DataSet tempTaskDS = new DataSet("tempCars");
tempTaskDS.Tables.Add("Cars");
tempTaskDS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(carDataRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

First **make sure your target DataSet / DataTable is the same as the source DataSet / DataTable with regards to column count, column types** etc. then use

```
targetDataSet.Tables["CarList2"].ImportRow(sourceRow)
```